# Fire event after successful data binding

Tags: events, data-binding, callback, sapui5

I want to fire an event after successful data binding of table control (after 'bindRows') to perform other other operations after data populated in control. Can any one help me how it can be done. I am tried but might be syntax is not correct hence it is not working.

```
tableControl.bindRows("odata model", {
                                     success:function(){
                                            alert('success');
                                          }
                                     });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `bindRows` method does not have `success` option in it's binding object.

To know when binding for rows of table is completed you need to attach `dataReceived` event to rows binding.

```
oTable.getBinding("rows").attachDataReceived(function(){
    alert("Success");
})
```